# LARAVEL_MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel-5.6

I read other answers about my question but they were useless for me.
I can't solve this error.

```
<form method="post" action="/cards/{{ $cards->id }}/notes">
     <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="body" title="body" class="form-control" style="text-align: center"></textarea>
     </div>
     <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>   
     </div>
</form>
```

and :

```
Route::get('cards', 'CardsController@index');
Route::get('cards/{cards}', 'CardsController@show');
Route::post('cards/{cards}/notes', 'NotesController@store');
```

thank for your help

Comment: Why are you sending the id in the action the type of action is not allowed in laravel when you can directly send the id to the controller via route Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {}); check this url https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing

Comment: I check this url but I still get this message

Comment: @BM How you define your NotesController@store function? does it accept an argument to receive id?

Comment: public function store(Request $request, Card $cards){$note = new Note;
        $note->body = $request->body;
        $cards->notes()->save($note);return back();}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add a CSRF token to your form. Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="/cards/{{ $cards->id }}/notes">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="body" title="body" class="form-control" style="text-align: center"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Note</button>   
    </div>
</form>
```